# How to get hold of a http-only cookie value in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, next.js, cookie-httponly

I am developing a web app using Next.js and I used HTTP-only cookies to manage authentication. I set a cookie called token using the following code. I used an npm package called [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) for this

```
 res.setHeader(
    "Set-Cookie",
    cookie.serialize("token", data.jwt, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
      sameSite: "strict",
      path: "/",
    })
  );
```

Now when I use `console.log(req.headers.cookie);` it logs a cookie like `_ga=GA1.1; token=jnsjndjsnjd` this. So my question is how can I get hold of the second cookie called token.
When I do `console.log(req.headers.cookie.token)` it says undefined.

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to log the cookie value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find the solution. We need to parse the cookie using `cookie.parse`, so we can access the token cookie as `req.headers.cookie.token`.